# How to merge data from one table to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have table like this :

Table A:

```
customerId     mobNo1    mobNo2    mobNo3
-----------------------------------------
123            999       997       987
124            888       666       555
```

Table B:

```
customerId     mobNumbers    
-------------------------
123            999       
123            997       
123            987       
124            888       
124            666       
124            555
```

I need to write a `MERGE` statement so that the data from tableA to get updated or inserted in to tableB

This is what I tried:

```
MERGE tableB tgt
USING (SELECT * FROM tableA) src ON src.customerId = tgt.customerId

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET mobNumbers = src.mobNo1,
            mobNumbers = src.mobNo2,
            mobNumbers = src.mobNo3,
 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (customerID, mobileNumbers)
    VALUES (src.customerID, src.mobNo1),
           (src.customerID, src.mobNo2), 
           (src.customerID, src.mobNo3);
END
```

But this is not working - any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Will a customer always have <= 3 numbers? I don't see "arbitrary" anywhere in the question but it seems the design is capped at 3. Can you explain how you determine when to update a row in B and how you pick (or how you expect SQL Server to pick) which one to update? What if all three have changed? What if two have changed? What if none have changed?

Comment: Can you explain why there are two different tables? What is the flow here? Are you able to revisit the design, how you store this data, and why you're storing it two different ways?

Comment: Yes customer will have <=3 in all cases and tableA is the response I receive from backed and I just need to compare it with tableB and update only the modified customers.

Answer (score 5):

You can't say `SET col = something, col = something else` whether you use `MERGE` or not - each `SET` directive applies to exactly one row, so mentioning the same column multiple times and expecting that to affect multiple rows differently is just not how it works.

The simplest approach IMHO doesn't involve `MERGE` at all (and not just because of [my long-standing bias against it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) or that [several people agree](https://sqlblog.org/merge)); just delete the customers that match and then insert the new set for each customer. This doesn't have error handling, but is the cleanest path IMHO:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- just wipe out all existing rows for matching customers
DELETE b FROM dbo.tableB AS b
  INNER JOIN dbo.tableA AS a
  ON a.customerId = b.customerId;

-- re-populate the whole set for each matching customer
INSERT dbo.tableB(customerId, mobNumbers)
  SELECT customerId, mobNumbers
  FROM dbo.tableA AS a
  UNPIVOT (mobNumbers FOR mobs IN ([mobNo1],[mobNo2],[mobNo3])) AS u
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tableB WHERE customerId = a.customerId);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: That may be problematic if `tableB` is referenced by other tables. Or if it has a lot of pre-existing data in it. Probably not the case here, though.

Comment: @Branko An update or merge is just a delete/insert pair behind the scenes, so whether you're updating or merging or deleting/inserting manually, you're affecting the same number of rows, incurring the same amount of log activity, should be taking the same locks, etc. The only difference would be if the majority of pairs of values already existed. You could do more on the `DELETE` to make sure you're not deleting customers that effectively don't have any changes, but the presumption is if they made it into the first table it's because of a change. Foreign key is of course unlikely here.

Comment: There is no need to delete or update any rows. We can just add the missing rows.

Comment: @Branko You don't think you need to delete rows? What if there's a `mobNumbers` value in `B` that doesn't exist in `A`? You don't need to delete it? I think the process is "here's the new set of three numbers for this customer" not "here are three new numbers for this customer." We *may* not need to delete rows for a given customer, but saying we will never have to do that I think misses part of the goal. I agree that we don't ever need to update rows in this scenario.

Comment: Well, the OP thinks that ;). Quote: "data from tableA to get updated or inserted in to tableB". And this kind of makes sense, considering `tableB` is designed to hold arbitrary number of phone numbers per customer. But yes, if I needed to delete something, I'd add the corresponding clause into MERGE.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic My interpretation was they thought they would need to update if, say, 555 was in B but wasn't in A, and 777 was in A but wasn't in B, and the other two numbers matched. Since A has only three columns, it doesn't seem like a logical conclusion that B must support an arbitrary number of numbers for a given customer. And like I said in an earlier comment, you could make the delete more discriminatory so that you might only ever end up with inserts or no-ops for some customers, but if the number of numbers is capped at 3, you couldn't guarantee no deletes would ever be needed.

Comment: *it doesn't seem like a logical conclusion that B must support an arbitrary number of numbers* - the `tableB` has a key on `{customerId, mobNumbers}`, not just `customerId`, which supports the arbitrary number of numbers per customer. Whether that was intentional or not, I cannot say.

Comment: @Branko My car has a fictitious key on `{VIN, tire}` but it's limited to four values for tire (`FL`, `FR`, `RL`, `RR`), not an arbitrary number. I don't see a key formally defined in the question, but you've taken quite a leap from "6 sample rows and a source table that explicitly limits the mobile numbers to 3" to "they must have meant to support an infinite number of mobile numbers."

Comment: The `tableB` has 2 fields, and therefore only 3 possible keys: `{customerId}`, `{mobNumbers}` and `{customerId, mobNumbers}`. Only the last one fits the data. If you want to limit the number of rows, this is not the right model. Like I implied, whether this fits the actual requirements is a different question, but looking at my phone's contacts app I don't see why it shouldn't. OTOH, your car model works only because you have limited the values (i.e. you have a CHECK or static lookup table somewhere), but that would probably be better represented akin to `tableA` - with separate fields.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic We don't know the OP's model; we only know what they've shown in the question. `tableA` certainly seems to explicitly limit a customer to _at most_ three mobile numbers, and I see nothing in the question that leads me to believe their intention is different (e.g. support unlimited mobile numbers in `tableB` but only three values in `tableA`). If they intended to support more mobile numbers, why aren't there more columns in `tableA`? You jump to conclusions about the only thing a key in `tableB` could mean to you, but completely ignore it for `tableA`?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Let's let the OP answer questions about design/intent instead of bickering about it, ok?

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that one source row maps into 3 target rows, so you need to "massage" the source appropriately.

I haven't actually tested it, but something like this should put you on the right track:

```
MERGE tableB tgt
USING
    (
        SELECT customerId, mobNo1 mobNo FROM tableA
        UNION
        SELECT customerId, mobNo2 FROM tableA
        UNION
        SELECT customerId, mobNo3 FROM tableA
    ) src
ON
    src.customerId = tgt.customerId
    AND src.mobNumbers = tgt.mobNo

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (customerID, mobileNumbers)
    VALUES (src.customerID, src.mobNo);
```

By the way, MERGE cannot modify the same row more than once (you'll get a run-time error if you try).

Comment: `MERGE` is not thread-safe; at the very least, you need a `SERIALIZABLE` hint (equivalent to `HOLDLOCK`) against the target. `MERGE` is one statement, but it's still multiple distinct operations, so it has the same vulnerabilities to race conditions / deadlocks as individual statements.

Comment: Sure, but the same holds for DELETE/INSERT combo. But concurrency control is really orthogonal to this question, IMO.

Comment: Yes and I wrapped the DELETE/INSERT combo in a serializable transaction. It is best practice to add this to all MERGE commands because without it you perpetuate the myth that you don't need it.

Comment: A serializable transaction will hold the read locks until the end of the transaction, blocking/deadlocking other transaction. Whether this is a problem largely depends on the number or rows being locked and the length of the transaction. If this really needs to be concurrent with readers, i think SNAPSHOT would be worth a look.

Comment: It needs to survive (well, prevent) concurrency with other writers. It has nothing to do with readers. They're two+ different write operations, even in a `MERGE`. `SERIALIZABLE` provides exactly the kind of blocking (not deadlocking) you want. You should _want_ your `MERGE` command to hold locks against the rows you're changing until the end of the transaction. If you don't, that's chaos. Also, not everyone can just turn on `SNAPSHOT`, it takes planning and testing.

Comment: SNAPSHOT should do that too. Or just put an UPDATE lock on the entire table (so we don't block readers). :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do without those UNION using UNPIVOT

Create tables and insert data

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
    customerId INT
    , mobNo1 INT
    , mobNo2 INT
    , mobNo3 INT )
CREATE TABLE #TableB (
    customerId INT
    , mobNumbers INT )
INSERT #TableA VALUES 
      (123, 999, 997, 988)
    , (124, 888, 666, 555);
INSERT #TableB VALUES
      (123, 999)
    , (123, 997)
    , (123, 987)
    , (124, 888)
    , (124, 666)
    , (124, 555);
```

The unpivot will "join" the columns that are descripted, you can see the command alone:

```
SELECT * FROM #TableA
UNPIVOT (
    Value
    FOR Origin
        IN (mobNo1, mobNo2, mobNo3)) Unp
```

If you do it like this, it's easier to put new columns in the query, only write the name of the column in the unpivot

Merge:

```
MERGE #TableB B
USING (
    SELECT * FROM #TableA
    UNPIVOT (
        Value
        FOR Origin
            IN (mobNo1, mobNo2, mobNo3)) Unp
    ) A
    ON
        B.customerId = B.customerId
        AND B.mobNumbers = A.Value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES (customerId, Value)
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN   --This option only if you want to delete the numbers that aren't in #TableA
    --  DELETE
    ;
```